# Combo box not focusable

Tags: ios, livecode

Is there any way we can set the combo box not focusable? Because every time I select an item from combo box (drop down list), the keyboard shows up and the text from drop down list can be edited. I can't find any property from property inspector to disable this up. Or maybe we can disable this one programmatically in which I don't know.

Comment: It looks like you are making an app for iOS. I would recommend not to use a combobox or option menu in iOS. Instead, you might want to use a (fake) list menu similar to the native lists like in the top-left or top-right in the picture on this website http://www3.economy-x-talk.com/file.php?node=ios-gui-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an Option Menu (unlike a Combo Box an Option Menu has no field which a user can type into - and therefore no unwanted appearance of the keyboard)

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The default script for a combo box is a menuPick handler. Whether or not you use the functionality of that handler or not, you would add this line at the end of that handler: